# Error on empty F# fsx file , VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, f#

In an empty *.fsx file in my F# Project I get the error:

`Invalid namespace, module, type or union case name`

[image]

I never had this problem before, What went wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: ... why do you need an empty file anyway? I guess you can fix it with a single line like `module EmptyOnPurpose`

Comment: It somes right after creating a new fsx file.

Comment: another thing: if I don't include whitespace (and the +) in the file name I don't have this issue either (the default module is named just like the file - that's most likely the origin of the problem) - but is this really an issue?

Comment: I have many script files that work well without "module"

Comment: as I said - look at your name: `merge Kiron + JSON` is not a valid name - to be clear: it's the `+` - it will work if you just remove this (never have this issue as I always enter either an module-name or a namespace at the start of my files - yes even the scripts)

Comment: Yes it is the file name. It is a one time script so I was not strict about the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to fix this either:

- **either** change the file name (`+` is not ok)
- **or** add a `module ...` on top (``` module ``merge Kiron and JSON`` ``` will do)